# Can all problems be formulated in terms of constraints?

Tags: alloy

Here's my understanding about modeling using Alloy:

An Alloy model of a problem has two parts:

1. A specification of the structural parts of the problem.
2. A specification of the constraints on the structural parts.

Can all problems be formulated in terms of constraints? Are there problems that cannot be formulated in terms of constraints, and therefore cannot be modeled using Alloy? If yes, would you provide an example please?

Are there problems that can be formulated in terms of constraints, but are best formulated in other ways? If yes, would you provide an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the nature of logic, almost any artifact can be described in logical terms. So, as you correctly note, the question is more what can be conveniently and compellingly expressed. I'd say that the principal alternative to a constraint based approach like Alloy is one based on explicit sequencing, as in CSP (and before that Michael Jackson's JSD). I actually wrote my masters thesis on these two as dual paradigms. It was called something like "Combining data and process descriptions". For some relevant reading, see Pamela Zave's early papers on operational specification, and her papers with Michael Jackson on multiparadigm description.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is implicit in formal models? When you define your sig's in Alloy you start with all possible states that those sigs can reach. Constraints then remove the states that are not desirable or not practical (e.g. the scope is a constraint that makes the model calculable). I compare it with sculpting; you start with a block of granite and remove the unwanted parts.

So the question is if the granite suffices? I think it is will be hard to give a theoretical complete answer since Gödel is always lurking around the corner. However, practically there are clearly limitations. The scope is clearly one but many common problems are difficult to model due to lack of syntactic sugar. However, despite these limitations I find that Alloy does provide me a handle to analyze the structure of existing software.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Kriens. I really like your sculpting granite analogy!